# Oracle Apex session end when click a button

Tags: oracle, session, plsql, oracle-apex, sessionend

In Oracle Apex I have a region that contains a text field and a button  that when clicked on a dynamic action is executed and a pl/sql statement runs which inserts the text_field value into a table.

The issue is when I click on the button the insertion is done, but when I come back to Oracle Apex I encountered the

> " your session is end "

error

How can I solve this?

Comment: With the information you provided, this is hard to debug. Could you post a minimal reproducible example with exact details of the complete dynamic action ? Ideally do this on the emp/dept dataset, anyone using apex can then reproduce the issue.

Comment: Unrelated to the question but please avoid writing anything in ALL CAPS. This is considered shouting and offensive.